# Helper for array of objects in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 helper function. This function simply takes an array of ojects and return images based on the url in each object. For some reason, I cannot seem to print the images...I just get back the array.

for example:

```
def my_helper(items)
 items.each do |item|
   image_tag(item)
 end
end
```

this returns the array. I've tried assigning to a variable and outputting, but no luck. I've seen where people say just use `item.join('<br/>')` but I didn't get that to work.

Help appreicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def my_helper(items)
  items.map do |item|
    image_tag(item)
  end.join('<br/>')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) method returns the original list it iterates over (in your example, `items`). To get what you want, you can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
def my_helper(items)
  items.map do |item|
    image_tag(item)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried map, but it doesn't work. It returns an array of the text links, not the rendered images. So for example it returns: [<img src=image1.jpg/>, <img src=image2.jpg />], rather than rendering the images. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's returning a string which wraps an array of strings...I don't need a string returned...that's my problem.